# How to get rid of docker-compose empty variable warnings that are only used in image builds and not at runtime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a build script which defines the values of following variables to be used by `docker-compose` at runtime.

```sh
# build.sh
...
export FOO="foo"
export BAR="bar"
export BINARIES_DIR="./"
export BUILD_SRC=`pwd`
docker-compose build
```

And this is service definition in compose:

```yaml
services:
  service_container:
    image: blabla:tag
    build:
      dockerfile: ${BUILD_SRC}/dockerfiles/Dockerfile.service
      context: "${BINARIES_DIR}"
      args:
        FOO: ${FOO}
        BAR: ${BAR}
    container_name: alpha_null
    network_mode: "host"
    privileged: true
    .
    .
    .
    command: /bin/bash
```

Once I build my service, I start the container using `docker-compose up`.

During build, docker-compose expands the variables as passed in the shell script.

*Evidently no variables defined in build/dockerfile/context are needed to start the container.*

But I get these warnings which I want to get rid of:

```sh
WARNING: The BUILD_SRC variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The BINARIES_DIR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The FOO variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The BAR variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I have seen related issues that advocate using `env` files to define variables inside the container. But in this case I need the variables only at build time, and not at runtime. How to get rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to split these details out of the main `docker-compose.yml` file.

Since it looks like your script is basically passing in every build option to the Compose setup, it might be easier to put the `docker build` command in your wrapper script, and remove the `build:` block from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# build.sh
...
docker build \
  --build-arg FOO=foo \                 # arg:
  --build-arg BAR=bar \                 # arg:
  -f ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile.service \ # dockerfile:
  -t blabla:tag                         # image:
  .                                     # context:
```

Another option is to use [two Compose YAML files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).  Create a second Compose file that *only* contains the `build:` definitions:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service_container:
    build:
      dockerfile: ${BUILD_SRC}/dockerfiles/Dockerfile.service
      context: "${BINARIES_DIR}"
      args:
        FOO: ${FOO}
        BAR: ${BAR}
    # No runtime options
```

Then in your build script, invoke this overlay file

```sh
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.build.yml \
  build
```

In both cases you need to remove the `build:` definitions from the main `docker-compose.yml` file.  That in turn will remove the environment-variable references and get rid of those warnings.